# Requirements to join the Wights (The Army of the Dead)

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In Game of Thrones Season 5, we see that the **wildlings** killed by Wights revive as Wights themselves. Jon Snow, Lord Commander of the Night's Watch, gets hurt while battling the wights and one of the White Walkers. Later, he gets stabbed by his brothers in the Watch.

As he got hurt by the Wights and the Walker, does that mean he would revive as a Wight himself? Or is it such that those who get killed at the hands of a Wight only will revive as a Wight?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe that being raised as a wight requires active work on the part of the Walkers; I don't believe anyone killed by a wight will resurrect themselves automatically. Beyond that, I don't think we know all of the details about how that process works, what's required, etc. The only time, as far as I can remember, that we've seen it at work is the huge battle near the end of Season 5, where the Night King personally raised an army of dead wildlings as wights.

It's also pretty clear that the characters in-universe don't understand it either. The Night's Watch is hyper-aware of the possibility of their dead coming back to life. They have burned the corpses of dead Night's Watchmen before. In fact, I believe in the Saason 6 trailer we've seen them trying to burn Jon's body as well, despite there being little chance of a Walker getting near it.

Comment: Oh... the Night King himself resurrects the dead men? btw, I think he would revive Jon Snow.. He seemed very interested when Jon killed a walker

Comment: i suspect the nights watchmen are all thinking the same thing...